# Как происходит вызов виртуального метода через интерфейс?

Tags: c#, интерфейс, clr

Товарищи, где-то 4 часа назад мне стало до жути интересно, как же происходит вызов виртуального метода объекта из-под обертки интерфейса...
Как вы понимаете, я так и не достиг успеха в своем стремлении познать суть сего вопроса...

---

Итак, давайте представим следующий код:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void DoWork();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm working!");
    }
}

...

ITest test = new Test();
test.DoWork(); // I'm working!
```

В подобном коде нет ничего удивительного, его результат вполне ожидаем... пока ты не задумаешься, а как же все таки это работает?

---

Пройдемся по пунктам:

```
ITest test = new Test();
```

Здесь мы создаем новый объект и сохраняем его в переменную с типом `ITest`. Если залезть в таблицу методов переменной `test`, то адрес ее будет равняться адресу таблицы методов типа `Test`

Все как и ожидалось, так что идем дальше:

```
test.DoWork(); // I'm working!
```

А вот тут начинаются темные делишки!
Каким образом среда находит метод, который необходимо вызвать? С этим вопросом я и просидел все это время...

Самый распространенный (и практически единственный) ответ на сие ссылается на данную таблицу:

[image: old]

Таблица методов содержит в себе указатель на `Interface Virtual Table Map`, внутри которого есть информация о том, где же начинается имплементация методов конкретного интерфейса

Все бы хорошо, да с тех пор среда `CLR` претерпела множество серьезных изменений, одним из которых является перестроенная таблица методов

На данный момент ее структура лучше всего описывается данной картинкой:
[image: new]

Как можно увидеть, никакой ссылки на `IVT Map` там больше нет, а сам раздел реализуемых типом интерфейсов был упрощен (теперь каждая запись занимает ровно `IntPtr.Size`, никаких дополнительных флагов и записей)...

На смену `IVT Map` пришла черная магия, не иначе, так как больше никаких явных указаний на то, какой метод должен быть вызван с использованием интерфейса, попросту не осталось

---

В поисках ответов, я полазил по памяти исполняемого процесса и получил следующие интересные результаты:

```
// Перейдем по адресу `Указатель на список методов` 
// внутри таблицы методов Test
0x7384b9e0 // Object.ToString
0x73840a30 // Object.Equals
0x7384e870 // Object.GetHashCode
0x7384b96c // Object.Finalize
0x015f02f8 // Test.DoWork

// Перейдем по адресу `Указатель на список методов` 
// внутри таблицы методов интерфейса ITest
0x015f02e8 // Test.DoWork - 0x10
0x00000080 // ???
0x00000000 // ???
0x015f02f8 // Test.DoWork
```

Каким образом сформировалось это чудо? И как по всему этому среда понимает, какой метод необходимо вызвать?

Ни один из найденных мною материалов не дал мне ответа на все эти вопросы...

Что думаете по сему поводу?

Comment: Не уверен что ты еще не видел данный ответ, но все-таки [@EricLippert: How does the callvirt .NET instruction work for interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014411/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy: таки видел (я до шестой страницы Google дошёл хД), в общих чертах механизм понятен, но вот конкретика... Предлагаемая статья в соседнем номере датируется 2005 годом и содержит достаточно старую информацию на сей счёт (о чем я писал в начале вопроса)

Comment: Можно кстати на enSo тоже задать такой вопрос

Comment: @Grundy: я встречал там подобные вопросы (которые относятся уже к, так скажем, современному CLR), право они без ответа ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Здесь еще важен текст :-) так что одним больше - хуже не станет :-) а вероятность что ответит кто-нить из причастных выше :)

Comment: @Grundy: у меня там рейтинг минимальный, меня всерьёз не воспринимают с подобными вопросами хД

Comment: Ты попробуй сначала :-)

Comment: @Grundy: таки само собой)

Comment: В этой книге в главе 6, объясняется как это работает http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0455-2.html, но книга тоже древняя)

Comment: @Yaroslav: да вот я боюсь ее древности. 2002 год, ещё до «перестройки»... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, это да, ну чего то другого найти не удается.

Comment: Мне кажется, что все просто. Так-то класс реализует всего 1 интерфейс и скорее всего среде для поиска не нужно много знаний для сопоставления=> зачем хранить какие-то таблицы? Я думаю, что интересности будут тогда, когда класс реализует несколько интерфейсов и явно.

Comment: @iluxa1810: `зачем хранить` - для единообразия. Уж лучше пожертвовать лишней парой байт, нежели плодить условные переходы. Как я понял из всего прочитанного, среда кэширует для интерфейса реализации методов типа, который в данный момент используется. Так что частая смена типов приведёт к падению производительности из-за невозможности адекватной работы предсказателя переходов. Вот только вопрос: как среда понимает, какие именно методы брать...

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/virtual-stub-dispatch.md

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ну фиг его знает... Так то техника сейчас умная и может это все закешировать+предсказания переходов в районе 95%.

Comment: таки где вопрос на enso? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: таки сегодня-завтра опубликую) Там нужно будет в пост больше деталей добавить. Если бы я сей вопрос перевёл и прямо так бы опубликовал, его бы раза 3 закрыли как дубликат, не разобравшись в том, что все остальные ответы на SO не вносят **детальной** конкретики в происходящее

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, будем посмотреть :-)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, уж полночь близится, а вопроса на enSo все нет :)

Comment: @Grundy: я сделал лучше: задал вопрос **VladD** хД Картинка потихоньку начинает проясняться

Comment: Не забудь ответ написать :)

Comment: @Grundy: смотрю, Вас этот вопрос тоже очень интересует хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, конечно :-)

Comment: еще лучше пускай @VladD ответ напишет :-)

Comment: @Grundy: он не вернётся, пока не увидит от Николаса обещанных изменений, увы... Так что если хотите с ним переговорить - пишите в *запрещенный на территории ruSO* чатик)

Comment: Ну как дети, ей-богу :)

Comment: @Grundy: позиция есть позиция. И, как мне кажется, она, мягко говоря, не лишена смысла ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Таки где вопрос на enSO и ответ тут? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: вопрос на enSO уже не имеет смысла задавать (так как за исключением пары деталей все уже выяснено), а ответ здесь будет сразу, как расквитаюсь с делами, ибо писать много)

Comment: i'm watching you :-D

Comment: @Grundy: я таки заметил хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, уж середина апреля близится, а ответа все нет :)

Comment: @Grundy: когда-нибудь настанет тот прекрасный светлый день, когда я таки опубликую ответ)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, таки пора бы уже

Comment: @Grundy: последний заказ завершу и найду время все описать)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, вот и май начался :)

Comment: @Grundy: чудесный месяц, не правда ли? ХД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, еще один месяц без ответа :-)

Comment: @Grundy: никто не забыт, ничто не забыто

Comment: Таки давай ответ же!

Comment: @Grundy: у меня такое чувство, что знайте Вы мой адрес, я бы уже писал его под дулом пистолета :D

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Grundy уже в пути :-D

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, таки ответа все еще нету!

Comment: @Grundy: а теперь и не будет. Я окончательно ушел в SOпротивление™️)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, тогда стоит удалить вопрос :-) смысл ему висеть не отвеченым? :)

Comment: @Grundy: чтобы помнили, что на этот вопрос могли ответить только два человека, ныне ушедшие в изгнание (один из которых и вовсе местная живая легенда)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, на самом деле все кто видел уже забыли, остальным это и не было интересно

Comment: @Grundy: вот именно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Так что останутся у нас скоро одни домашки и `что такое "!!"??` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, либо просто будут отвечать другие (¬‿¬)

Comment: SOпротивлению бы Ваш оптимизм, товарищ @Grundy)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95770/discussion-between-grundy-and-kir-antipov).